# Issue with writing recursive function. discord

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to adapt this script so that even if multiple messages are sent at the same time the script will just keep trying until they are let through.

The original script is: https://github.com/4rqm/dhooks

My version is:

```
def post(self):
    """
    Send the JSON formated object to the specified `self.url`.
    """ 

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    result = requests.post(self.url, data=self.json, headers=headers)

    if result.status_code == 400 or result.status_code == 429:
        print(result.status_code)
        #its the line below that does not work.
        post(self)
    else:
        print("Payload delivered successfuly")
        print("Code : "+str(result.status_code))
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Your code seems to be missing some context - if `post` is actually a method in a class, you'd need to use `self.post()` to invoke it recursively.  (Not that recursion is a good approach to solve this problem, but it should work as long as you always need less than a thousand retries.  A `while` loop would be a better idea.)

Comment: Yes apologies for the missing context. You're suggestion was correct, in a daze at the moment. Thank you